# consistency of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory

For some sentence P,

If when we try to prove that

"It is impossible to disprove P in ZFC"

(it means there no valid proof in ZFC such that insists P is disprovable)

Do we always need assumption of consistency of ZFC?

Comment: If ZFC is not consistent, then $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\varphi$ for every $\varphi$ in the language of set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If ZFC is inconsistent then every statement in the language of ZFC is provable in ZFC. So any theorem showing that even one statement is not provable must assume, one way or another, that ZFC is consistent.

Comment: thank you. I want ask same additional question as to Brian. Without the assumption of consistency, ZFC cannot prove that " it is impossible to disprove '3 + 4 = 2 + 5 ' " ? And what about Godel theorem.....Godel already proved that "it is impossible to disprove Godel sentence

Comment: Yes - those theorems need the assumption of consistency. Gödel's theorem in particular explicitly assumes that the theory in question is consistent.

Comment: thank you again. ....but.. " 3+4 = 2+5 " is true. How can we disprove it?

Comment: Consider a theory that has the negation of that statement as an axiom. Certainly that theory can disprove the statement.

Comment: Yes, but ZFC theory doesn't include such axiom, ¬"3+4 = 2+5"

Comment: In principle ZFC might contain a collection of axioms which, together, imply that particular axiom. The point of assuming that ZFC is consistent is to eliminate any such possibility.

Comment: thank you. You gave me a good answer.